# Unit Testing (Angular) Error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

i got a problem when im writing test in angular the fact that i wanna test routing of button but it got error like this

**this is my homepage.component.spec.ts file** (this is not app.component.spec.ts file)

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { inject } from '@angular/core/src/render3';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { RegisterpageComponent } from'../registerpage/registerpage.component';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

describe('HomepageComponent', () => {
  let component: HomepageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomepageComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule],
  declarations: [ HomepageComponent,
                  AppComponent,
                  RegisterpageComponent ]
})
.compileComponents();
}));


beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomepageComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});

// tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
let location: Location;
// tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
let router: Router;
// tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const

router = TestBed.get(Router);
location = TestBed.get(Location);

router.initialNavigation();

it('navigate to "registerpage"', () => {
  router.navigate(['register']);
  expect(location.path()).toBe('/register');
 });
});
```

**this is app-routing.module.ts file**

```
import { ApplicationRef, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { RegisterpageComponent } from './registerpage/registerpage.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '',
    //   redirectTo: '/home',
         component: HomepageComponent,
         pathMatch: 'full' },


     { path: 'register',
       component: RegisterpageComponent}
  // { path: '**',
  //   component: PagenotfoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

i have stuck with this for a week and seem like no hope please help me! Thanks

ps.actually im confusing that i have to write test code in AppComponent.spec.ts file or not

Comment: see this article https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/ will help you I think

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem and hit this question during my search for an answer.

The following lines should be moved to the beforeEach.

```
router = TestBed.get(Router);
location = TestBed.get(Location);
router.initialNavigation();
```

In full....

```
let location: Location;
let router: Router;

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomepageComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();

  router = TestBed.get(Router);
  location = TestBed.get(Location);
  router.initialNavigation();
});
```